# Access user email using new Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Hi I'm playing with new Facebook Android SDK. One thing I could not figure out is how can I ask for email address. I tried following but it returned values for all fields except email address. I guess I probably have to ask permission separately for email address but not sure how I can do that if I use LoginFragment.

```
Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        profilePictureView.setUserId(user.getId());
        userNameView.setText(user.getName());
    }
});

String NAME = "name";
String ID = "id";
String PICTURE = "picture";
String EMAIL = "email";
String FIELDS = "fields";
String REQUEST_FIELDS = TextUtils.join(",", new String[] {
    ID, NAME, PICTURE, EMAIL
});

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString(FIELDS, REQUEST_FIELDS);
request.setParameters(parameters);
Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you must specify the sdk version instead of mentioning 'new Facebook android sdk', I guess

Answer (score 30):

Do the following:

After setting the permissions as above access the email via:
user.asMap().get("email"));

See the example below

```
@Override
protected void onSessionStateChange(SessionState state, Exception exception) {

    // user has either logged in or not ...
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        // make request to the /me API
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(this.getSession(),
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    // callback after Graph API response with user object

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                            Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (user != null) {
                            TextView etName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);

                            etName.setText(user.getName() + ","
                                    + user.getUsername() + ","
                                    + user.getId() + "," + user.getLink()
                                    + "," + user.getFirstName()+ user.asMap().get("email"));

                        }
                    }
                });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we get the profile picture as well using this method? (I mean by using a Request class)

Comment: I attempted to set read permissions like this : `authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));` and then tried to access the email like this `user.asMap().get("email")` but it always returns `null`.

Comment: see the report from Facebook [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298946933534016).

Comment: @toobsco42 reason it retunrs null that,  your given account doent give permission to provide email, try it with another account .

Comment: what will happen if we dont provide permission to access email address, can we ask from app itself to give email address from user

Answer (score 24):

When you open the Session, try including "email" in the list of permissions.

If you are using LoginButton, do something like:

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
```

If you are opening the Session yourself, do something like:

```
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email")));
```

You can experiment with requests/permissions using: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Once you have logged in successfully with these permissions, then try the request again including the email field.

Comment: If you use build-in LoginFragment from SDK how can you pass the extra field?

Comment: LoginFragment also has a setReadPermissions method.

Comment: Iam requesting emial as Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
   openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(LoginActivity.this);

   if (openRequest != null) {

    openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);

    openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
    mCurrentSession.openForRead(openRequest);

   } but I am getting null for Log.d("user email",
          (String) user.getProperty("email")
          );

Comment: You are getting null because you need to make sure you set the permissions in the Facebook application in the permissions on the actual Facebook application webpage.

Comment: loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email")) didn't work for me. Don't know if something else I did was the problem or this no longer works. I successfully used Golan Shay's answer.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton` you should set permissions to this fragment, after that facebook returns email. Here is working code:

```
LoginButton authButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_facebook);
    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
    permissions.add("public_profile");
    permissions.add("email");
    permissions.add("user_birthday");
    authButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);`
```

**EDIT**
Facebook updated it's sdk, which facilitated the work with it. Starting from 4.x version([changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x)) you can initialize sdk in diferent places where you need it and than use it in very simple way. Here is sample:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                    String email = object.optString("email");
                                    String uid = object.optString("id");
                                    loginPresenter.loginBySocial(email, uid);
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "email");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                  //your code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                  //your code
                }
            });
```

Comment: i am searching from past few days...your answer helped me thanx

Comment: @vovaxo I am new to Android FB integration. Once this is done, where do I get the email of the user?

Comment: @Teju there is interface that you should implement `Session.StatusCallback`. Inside callback method: ` @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState sessionState, Exception e) {
        if (sessionState.isOpened() && session.isOpened()) {

Request me = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser graphUser, Response response) {
                    String email = graphUser.asMap().get("email").toString();
                 }
            });
            me.executeAsync();
        }
    }`

Comment: this doesnt return email for some accounts , while other similar apps are working with same account with Facebook login, strange, any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: and it works

```
LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment() {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
                setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
                return v;
            }
        };
```