# Facebook SDK 3.0 - Get Facebook User ID and Access Token

Tags: android, facebook

I searched for past two days and was not successful in finding the method to get the user id and access token from Facebook SDK 3.0 - Native Login .

i am following facebook native login - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/

and i get the access token using `Session.getAccessToken` , i get some access token but that is not valid . what is the actual procedure ? Am i doing wrongly ?

How to get the `UserId` in Native Login using Facebook SDK 3.0

Answer (score 38, accepted):

user id:

```
final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // If the session is open, make an API call to get user data
        // and define a new callback to handle the response
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // If the response is successful
                if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        user_ID = user.getId();//user id
                        profileName = user.getName();//user's profile name
                        userNameView.setText(user.getName());
                    }   
                }   
            }   
        }); 
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
    }
```

`user_ID` & `profileName` are string.

for accessToken:

```
String token = session.getAccessToken();
```

**EDITED: (13/1/2014)**

for user email (i haven't check this code by running on device or emulator):

these are only my opinion or you can call it suggestion

```
setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", ...other permission...));
//by analyzing the links bellow, i think you can set the permission in loginbutton as:
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", ...other permission...));
user.asMap().get("email");
```

for more info see:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205517/access-user-email-using-new-facebook-android-sdk), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014117/getting-email-address-by-using-facebook-sdk-3-0-1-for-android), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915236/get-user-id-and-email-using-facebook-sdk-android), [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609287/how-to-get-email-id-from-facebook-sdk-in-android-applications),

Comment: Here how to get user email??

Comment: @user2843350 : i have put some suggestion in the `EDITED: (13/1/2014)` part, check out and let me know. P.S.: i haven't work with Facebook SDK a long time