# Android - Facebook SDK get user name - Request.GraphUserCallback returns null

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to display my Facebook name with this simple app that login after a button click that calls `login()`.

The session is opened correctly, but the Request.GraphUserCallback does not work it seems that return null.

LogCat doesn't display any error when i launch my app, but i can't see my `user.name()` on the Toast that i showed on the onCompleted when the Graph API returns the user.

Here's my code without the imports and without the layout:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback;
private Request.GraphUserCallback requestGraphUserCallback;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ci siamo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       

    statusCallback= new SessionStatusCallback();

    requestGraphUserCallback = new RequestGraphUserCallback();    

}


public void login(View view){


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "finito login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


//CLASSE SESSIONE
private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

         if (session.isOpened()) {
          // make request to the /me API

             Request.newMeRequest(session, requestGraphUserCallback);
       }

    }
}


//CLASSE GRAPH

private class RequestGraphUserCallback implements Request.GraphUserCallback{

   // callback after Graph API response with user object
   @Override
   public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
       if (user != null) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
     }
   }

}
```

What i'm doing wrong?
Facebook documentation is very uncomprehensive.
Already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134978/how-to-get-id-and-name-from-facebook-profile-using-facebook-sdk/15137333#15137333) question and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_facebook_integration.htm) tutorial (that use the contract version of my code).

Comment: where you have set request permission, facebook sdk have sample login code go through that.

Comment: if you are talking about INTERNET permissions is on the Manifest file

Comment: not at all, facebook have own permission to read user's details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not executing the request. In your SessionStatusCallback, after creating the request, you should call the `executeAsync()` method on it.

Comment: I love you and you are my hero, after two days of searching in internet you saved my life. I resolved with:              Request.newMeRequest(session, requestGraphUserCallback).executeAsync();

Comment: FB SDK said executeMeRequestAsync was deprecated hence use newMeRequest, but in my effort to refactor the API, I missed this important step. Thank you good sir