# how to get Facebook user details like phone no,password from android Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.1

I found out how to get `username`, `user id`, `user email id` using the Facebook SDK. I still don't know how to get the `user phone no` and `user password`.

I am referring to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609287/how-to-get-email-id-from-facebook-sdk-in-android-applications?answertab=active#tab-top)

The example reads the `id`, the `username` and the `email`.

Could you tell me how to get the `user phone no` and the `user password` using the Facebook SDK.

Comment: but at-least phone no

Comment: I do not think that is going to be possible for every user, it depends if the user has kept their phone number public. Although at higher end, everything is possible.

Comment: but is it possible to get the user phone no? value null or data

Comment: Yes it is possible to get user phone number. For the people who have kept it public using Graph API, also for the people who have not. Although the later part of the previous statement is a bit twisted and is not related with Graph API.

Comment: then how to get phone no

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Facebook API does not let you access user's phone number and as they said this **will not be added anytime soon**. Therefore, You can't get either phone number or password from Facebook. You can authenticate your user without password using [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android). The phone number acquisition will have to be handled directly by your application, and the password can be the user's facebook id as an alternative solution.