# How to get Email id of user in Facebook in android?

Tags: android, facebook, email

I want to know that **how to get Email id Of user who is currently log in to the Facebook** when **connecting with Facebook using intent.**

I am using **Facebook with using intent.**

please share me some idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

there is a method which implements socialauthlistner using social auth library

link of library is https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth

```
// To receive the profile response after authentication
    private final class ProfileDataListener implements SocialAuthListener<Profile> {

        @Override
        public void onExecute(String provider, Profile Prof) {
        ProfileMap profileMap = Prof;


            email=profileMap.getEmail();

            Toast.makeText(this, ""+email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: But I am using FB application through intent not with using socialauth library. With intent how can I do that?

Comment: +1 For the Information.

Comment: Luckyy Nickey here is the solution for facebook sdk  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609287/how-to-get-email-id-from-facebook-sdk-in-android-applications

Comment: M using fb through ***"initShareIntent("com.facebook.katana");"***

Comment: try three pillar's library its quite easy buddy.. :)

Comment: Okk where i can find that?

Comment: https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth  on this link with useful examples