# Get user ID and Email using Facebook SDK Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the logged in user's id and email. Here is my code:

```
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email"));
          // session state call back event
          authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

   @Override
   public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        if (session.isOpened()) {
             Log.i(TAG,"Access Token"+ session.getAccessToken());
               Request.newMeRequest(session,
                   new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) {
           if (response != null) { 
              Log.i(TAG,"User ID "+ user.getId());
               Log.i(TAG,"Email "+ user.asMap().get("email"));
                 }
                }
              });
           }
          }
     });
```

Everything goes ok till here

```
Log.i(TAG,"Access Token"+ session.getAccessToken());
```

I can see the access token, but the `onComplete` method is not called, and i don't get any user info.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: is it possible that simply `response` is null ?

Comment: no, i even deleted the if statement, i still don't see anything from inside onComplete in logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if (user != null)
```

instead of

```
if (response != null)
```

or try

```
Request.newMeRequest(...).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you! i used `if (user != null)` and `Request.newMeRequest(...).executeAsync();`