# facebook android getEmail

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the user's email who has logged in with facebook.

This is my code `String userId=(String) user.asMap().get("email");` it return null, How can i fix it?

i read that there is maybe a session permissions that i need to set? what is this permission? and where do i need to write this permission?

maybe its another problem?

```
Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
        }

        updateView();

   //    End of OnCreate Method>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    private void updateView() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email")));

        if (session.isOpened()) {
            //button logout string
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogout(); }
            });
        } else {
            //button log in string
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
            });
        }
    }

    private void onClickLogin() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }

    private void onClickLogout() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isClosed()) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if( session.isOpened() ){
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                        String userId=(String) user.asMap().get("email");
                        i.putExtra("epuzzle",userId  );
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }
            updateView();
        }


    }
```

and this is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sale"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.sale.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.sale.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sale.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


              </activity>

         <!--  Entry for RegisterActivity.class -->
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
                  android:label="Register New Account"></activity>
        <meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" android:label="Profile page"></activity>

        <meta-data
              android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
              android:value="AIzaSyDTVRXMTmfe3jZyAlt-87kRgqM8y4TzIto"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with Facebook kind of API which requires Internet Permission. Follow this steps,

- Open Androidmanifest.xml file
- declare permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` after the  tag.

Comment: i already have a INTERNAT persmission in my manifest file, i dont think that this is the problem

Comment: @IdanRahamim, good, can you please upload the code of your AndroidManifest.xml  file ?

Comment: hi, i added my manifest file, i meant that facebook has a permission to get the user name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205517/access-user-email-using-new-facebook-android-sdk   , however i dont know where do i need to write this permission in my code? (also, i am not sure that this is the problem..)