# adding email permission to facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, permissions

I've been straggling for a while with this issue. I want to read users email once he is loged in using Facebook Login button. Here is my code

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
loginButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Access Token: " + session.getAccessToken());
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                                    Log.d(TAG,
                                            ""
                                                    + user.asMap().get("email")
                                                    + " is connected using facebook");

                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });
```

But I'm not even asked for email permission when approving the app. Thus I don't receive "email" in users JSON...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
user.asMap().get("email");
```

What the code above should do is take the `GraphUser` and turn it into a `Java Collections Map`. Now, you call the `get()` method on it with the `"email"` parameter which will look through the Map for an email field and return one if present. [Reference this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/GraphObject#asMap%28%29) for more information on `GraphObjects`. [And this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205517/access-user-email-using-new-facebook-android-sdk) for more information on how to get the user's email.

Comment: This is what I'm doing (I've updated the code in the question - there was a mistake in copying my code)..